# How to do search with Redis Client in ServiceStack?

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack

With the Redis C# client from ServiceStack, is there a way to search for values inside the JSON objects that are stored?

For example, we have keys:

```
urn:comment:1, urn:comment:2 etc and the corresponding values stored are:

"{Id:1, CommentText:"some text here that could be quite large..." ...} etc
```

A user may enter a string and want to see all Comment objects that contain the string entered.

How do you do this?

Comment: Your problem is not well suited for Redis. You cannot search in values, at all.

Comment: You need to explicitly index the data while they are inserted. You cannot perform an ad-hoc search, Redis is not a relational or a document-oriented database.

Comment: Thanks Didier, I came across the reverse index search earlier today.

Comment: It sounds like what you're after is something like Elastisearch- what you describe is exactly what it's designed to do (tokenized string search): http://www.elasticsearch.org/